# About complexity theory

Tags: computational-complexity

In complexity theory, The size of a linear circuit is given by the number of its nodes. What do we mean when we say superlinear size? and What do we mean when we say Nonlinear lower bounds?

Comment: The bounds apply to *parameterized families* of circuits.

Comment: Can you give me an example please

Comment: A classic example is the family of circuits that compute the parity of $n$ bits.  You can build circuits to compute the parity of $n$ bits that have $O(n)$ nodes.